# How to convert special font text in image to string in python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

The below code is converting the image text to string but its not accurate , some special characters are coming in between [sampe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkzJh.jpg)

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

image=Image.open('C://Users/Arjun/Desktop/1512350.jpg')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd='C://Program Files (x86)/Tesseract- 
OCR/tesseract'
result=pytesseract.image_to_string(image,config='-psm7 -c 
tessedit_char_whitlist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890')
print(result)
```

output:

> fl/'S‘TIW ° MILLER‘ 1003055666 ° gum/71; C6521:pmuzznmmimfmmpmy *5mg[e
>   * 2900456023 ° Uj7s564550 ° 130013 ° mm 5\1£®IC/‘(L 0£0wEmm'2zowLI5vg gazmyw 250 0’/lrkksrmgf" ﬂowzzyvg (jﬁff-W" M * 42101 ° wowiany " qw—
>   I’Va:/11/£172 ' J6 ’ 19955.65 * 5685.26 " 4586.65 ’ Safaxizf

Comment: What happens if you remove config altogether?

Comment: im getting almost same output even after removing the config

Comment: Which tessdata are you using?

Answer (score 0):

@Arjun, I think instead of passing an image directly, try applying some operations on image for getting better results. Try applying Threshold, like Binary Threshold, Adaptive threshold, Otsu_binary threshold and then try to get result. I think this might give you accurate result and let me know if you get stuck. Thanks

You can refer this link to understand use better Threshold techniques 
[Threshold Doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)